# Equivalent Resistance

Tags: resistors, current-source, inductance

I'm working on the following homework problem. (Yes, this is homework. :p ) I'm supposed to find the current through L1 as a function of time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6FEN0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using current division I've identified the current at zero time.

$$ I_L (0) = 0.01(15/(47+15)) = 2.42mA$$

However, I'm a little confused on how to find the equivalent resistance (since the Time Constant = Inductance/Equivalent Resistance.) Are they in parallel with each other? I guess the reason I'm confused is that my textbook said to find the equivalent resistance from the view of the inductor.

Note: The empty wire parallel to the inductor had a switch that was closed at t=0.

Comment: Hint:  transform the Norton circuit composed of I1 and R1 to its Thevenin form.

Comment: I had that done in my notes but that doesn't get rid of that middle empty cross connection. That's what's screwing with my mind right now

Comment: Is the wire placed or removed at *t = 0*?  It the wire is placed at *t=0*, the resistance seen by the inductor is obvious.

Comment: It is placed at t=0

Comment: Ah, I see. So because of that cross wire, you can ignore the 15 ohm resistor. So it's just the 47 ohm by itself correct?

Comment: Indeed!  0||15 = 0.

Comment: The magic of short circuits.

Comment: There won't be any current through L1, all the current will flow through the short(least resistance path) which is parallel to R1.

Comment: Unfortunately, the accepted answer missed the mark. Before the switch was closed at t=0, the current through the inductor was 2.4194 mA. After the switch closed, the constant 10 mA was shunted by the resulting short and the inductor’s current declined toward zero. The problem was to find that time-dependent inductor current, which the accepted answer did not do. If the switch had *always* been closed, then the inductor’s current would have *always* been zero.

Comment: This is a really old question, but the answer, from [here](https://physics.info/circuits-rl/), is i(t) = 2.4194 mA times exp(-t R2/L1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a trick question. Circuit is shorted, so all the current will flow through the wire. Current through \$L_1\$ is 0. Ran the SPICE sim just to be sure. Results and netlist below :)

[image: SPICE sim results]

```
I1 0 0 10m
R1 0 0 15
R2 0 N001 47
L1 N001 0 10m
.tran 0 10m 0 1u
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: You have neatly transcribed the comment into an answer.